# Page jumping (left and right) because of scrollbar

Tags: angularjs, user-experience

I'm creating an AngularJS application which has a loader, but since angular is really fast (yay), the page jumps between the loadings (nay :/) - what happens, is when the loading screen comes up, the scrollbar gets hidden and when a new page loads, the scrollbar is put back, this creates a flickering in the menu(always visible) part on top of the page.

Same thing happens when I open a pop-up or smth. like that. I add overflow: hidden; to the body in DOM so the user can't scroll when a pop-up is opened, but again this hides the browser scrollbar and the page jumps.

Any ideas how to solve this UX problem?

Comment: make the scrollbar always visible? `overflow: scroll`.

Comment: this does not do as the visitor would then be able to scroll :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a rather simple solution

```
html {
   height: 100.001%;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```